# Logic Pro - control region gain with MIDI controller

Tags: logic-pro, midi-controller-keyboard, mac

I would like to change region-specific gain with my MIDI controller. Is there any way to map this? Thanks!

[image: region-specific gain]

Comment: Have you checked this? https://support.apple.com/guide/logicpro/assign-and-delete-controllers-in-easy-view-ctls71c31855/mac

Comment: @musicamante I have. Logic Pro doesn't recognize changing region parameters.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I now get what you mean. I sincerely doubt it's possible, also considering that making midi mapping targeting specific regions would be very impractical (also from the programming point of view).